# Why does ~ :first-of-type not work as intended?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does this work,

```
querySelector("p + p");
```

but this below code returns `null`?

```
querySelector("p ~ p:first-of-type");
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also add some HTML and tell us what "does not work" means. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We need to see the related HTML that it doesn't work on. See [mcve]

Comment: @Zach it's because the second `p` is *second* of type I guess. try `p ~ p:nth-child(n+1):first-of-type`

Comment: How can a `p` coming after a `p` be the first of it's type?

Comment: My thought process is that it would be first-of-type from the p sibling not from the initial container. In my opinion the CSS code should know that because the ~ is there

Answer (score 0):

`p ~ p` means "A `p` that is **not** the first `p` among its siblings".

The type of the element is `p` so `p:first-of-type` means "A `p` that **is** the first `p` among its siblings".

If you combine them you have have mutually exclusive requirements. A `p` cannot be both the first `p` and **not** the first `p`.

Comment: My thought process was that the code should know that when a ~ is involved between them it would know to reset the count. It would be the first of type from the sibling not from the main container

Comment: @Zach — It doesn't. `:first-of-type` means "first of type among all its siblings", nothing more, nothing less.